# How would i go ahead in simulating a key hold until the key is released whilst waiting for a packet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

The issue at the moment is that the key is only pressing once and releasing... but this is not the desired action. As we would like it to hold as is done when a conventional keyboard key is held down.

I have attempted to use another library called PyAutoGui and attempted multithreading but threw both away because 1. Multithreading gave some weird WINERROR and 2. PyAutoGui does the same thing but much slower.

## Server

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller. Listener
from socket import *
import pickle
host = ""
port = 5000
buf = 1024
addr = (host, port)
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPSock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
UDPSock.bind(addr)
keyboard = Controller()
print("Waiting to receive messages...")

with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

while True:
    (data, addr) = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)
    data = pickle.loads(data)
    for dat in data:
        if(len(dat) == 1):
            keyboard.press(dat)
        elif(len(dat) > 1):
            keyboard.release(dat[:1])



    print("Received array: " + str(data))




UDPSock.close()
os._exit(0)
```

## Client

```
import pygame
import pickle
from socket import *
# Save as client.py
# Message Sender

def on_key_release(key):
    print('Released Key %s' % key)

def on_key_press(key):
    data = key
    print('Pressed key %s' % key)    

host = "##.##.##.##"  # set to IP address of target computer
port = 5000
addr = (host, port)
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))

while True:
    data = []
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                data.append('a')
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                data.append('d')
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                data.append('w')
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                data.append('s')
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                data.append('au')
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                data.append('du')
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                data.append('wu')
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                data.append('su')

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
                
    print(data)
    if(len(data) >= 1):
        data = pickle.dumps(data)
        UDPSock.sendto(data, addr)

UDPSock.close()
os._exit(0)
```

Expectations:
I'm expecting that when a packet saying d is received the keyboard is simulated to keep holding d until a packet du is obtained which signifies a key release. so that the character in Super Mario can keep moving to the right naturally. whilst also allowing for multiple inputs.

Edit:
It's been a month and still waiting anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

Pyautogui Should work. Have you tried using it like this?

```
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
time.sleep(3)#simulating Hold
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

Comment: yeah but i'm expecting more inputs and i want it to sleep until 'shift-u' is recieved which isn't logically sound